# jquery tooltip ipad bug

Tags: jquery, ipad, tooltip

Need some help. Ive been using tooltips on my site and everything is working finde except for the ipad. They are displaced.

Im using latest version of tooltips and jquery.

any idea?

tooltip code can be found in formular.js!

best regards

Comment: Ok did some testing. The problem appears while scrolling with iPad. So if I reload the site with no scrolling before (the site is on top) everything works as expected even if I scroll. But if the page is loaded with a scrolling amount the tooltips are displaced. Any idea on how to reset the scrolling of iPad with every page loading?

Comment: set scrollTop property of element with the scroll to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. If anyone is having the same problem on iPad and using jquery tooltips just delete the iPad Fix part!

```
// iPad position fix
if (/iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  top -= $(window).scrollTop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve the issue without editing jquery tools source:

```
selectedObj.tooltip({ 
    ...
    onBeforeShow : function(a, b){
      // fix for ipad
      if(isiPad)  {
         selectedObj.data('tooltip').getConf().offset = [$(window).scrollTop(), 0];
      }
    },
    ...
});
```